# Маскировка изображения, чтобы сделать его похожим на бинокль

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, svg, mask

Я пытался написать код, где изображение маскируется внутри элемента бинокулярной формы.

Круглая части маски перемещаются с помощью курсора мыши, и, куда бы она ни направлялась, они раскрывают часть изображения.
Также необходимо позиционировать мышь, не выходя из основного контейнера.

Изображение, которое должно получиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Остальная часть изображения останется черной, и только маскированные элементы будут видны в этой форме при перемещении мыши.

Я пробовал следующий код:

```js
$('.clipping-cursor').on('mousemove', function(e) {

    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
    var relativeXPosition = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left); //offset -> метод позволяет получить текущую позицию элемента «относительно» документа
    var relativeYPosition = (e.pageY - parentOffset.top);

    $('.clipping-cursor').css({
      left: relativeXPosition,
      top: relativeYPosition
    });
  });
```

```css
.collaborate-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.clipping-cursor {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 580px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -290px;
  margin-left: -500px;
  background-image: url('../images/background/collaborate-2.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: container;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-mask-image: url('../images/masking-circle.svg');
  -webkit-mask-size: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position: center;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collaborate-wrapper">
  <div class="clipping-cursor">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37090147/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете сделать это с помощью SVG и некоторого кода JS, чтобы менять положение маски при перемещении мыши

```js
$(".a").mousemove(function(e) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
  var relX = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left) - 55;
  var relY = (e.pageY - parentOffset.top) - 30;

  $('mask g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + relX + ',' + relY + ')');
});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/secondary/Planet-Nine-443937.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="400px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="white" />
      <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
        <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" />
        <circle cx="85" cy="30" r="30" />
      </g>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" class="one" mask="url(#mask)" width="400" height="200" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37091328/7394871): @Nenad Vracar

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант с увеличением маски после клика мышки на изображении**

```
<circle cx="85" cy="30" r="30" >
           <animate attributeName="r" dur="0.2s" values="30;45" fill="freeze" 
              begin="svg1.click" />
</circle
```

```js
$(".a").mousemove(function(e) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
  var relX = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left) - 55;
  var relY = (e.pageY - parentOffset.top) - 30;

  $('mask g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + relX + ',' + relY + ')');
});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/secondary/Planet-Nine-443937.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <svg id="svg1" x="0px" y="0px" width="400" height="200"  viewBox="0 0 400 200">
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="white" />
      <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
        <circle  cx="30" cy="30" r="30" >
     <animate attributeName="r" dur="0.2s" values="30;45" fill="freeze" begin="svg1.click" />
  </circle>
        <circle cx="85" cy="30" r="30" >
     <animate attributeName="r" dur="0.2s" values="30;45" fill="freeze" begin="svg1.click" />
  </circle>
      </g>
    </mask>
    <rect x="0" y="0" class="one" mask="url(#mask)" width="400" height="200" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

**Вариант с полупрозрачным фоном и увеличением маски по клику**

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <svg id="svg1" x="0px" y="0px" width="1200" height="600"  viewBox="200 0 1200 600" >
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="#151515" />
      <g transform="translate(0, 0)" fill="white">
        <circle  cx="30" cy="30" r="30"  >
     <animate attributeName="r" dur="0.2s" values="45;90" fill="freeze" begin="svg1.click" />
  </circle>
        <circle cx="85" cy="30" r="30"  >
     <animate attributeName="r" dur="0.2s" values="45;90" fill="freeze" begin="svg1.click" />
  </circle>
      </g>
    </mask>
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/npNcn.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#mask)" />
   <!--  <rect x="0" y="0" class="one" mask="url(#mask)" width="1200" height="600" /> -->
  </svg>
</div>
<script>
$(".a").mousemove(function(e) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
  var relX = (e.pageX - parentOffset.left) - 55;
  var relY = (e.pageY - parentOffset.top) - 30;

  $('mask g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + relX + ',' + relY + ')');
});
</script>
```

Источник ответа: @Alexandr_TT